# How to get Text from certain Area in a PDF-Document in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdfbox, pdf-reader

I want to get data from a certain Position in a PDF-Document.

I tried to get Text from a certain Area in a PDF with the pdfbox library.
But the addRegion method expects a Rectangle2D. Android only has the Rect class which is not a Rectangle2D.
Because of that I get an error on:

```
stripper.addRegion("class1", rect);
```

What can I do to overcome this?
Is there any other way to extract data
from a certain Position in a PDF-Document with the Android SDK? Any other Library that works for this? Because I don't think there is a Library for Android Studio for Rectangle2D.

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("/Users/osman/Desktop/test.pdf"));
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    stripper.addRegion("class1", rect);
    stripper.extractRegions(document.getPage(1));
    System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class1"));
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCP2I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution to my own Question:

There is a PDFBox Library for Android on GitHub. https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android

Add this to Android.Manifest dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:2.0.25.0'
}
```

The Code to extract Data is:

```
    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(path, "Test.pdf");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getApplicationContext());
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    RectF rect = new RectF(100, 100, 300, 300);
    stripper.addRegion("class1", rect);
    stripper.extractRegions(document.getPage(0));
    System.out.println(stripper.getTextForRegion("class1"));
```